# Ionic 2 convert to Ionic 3 : "Error: Failed to transpile program" on "ionic build iOS"

Tags: ios, node.js, npm, ionic2, ionic3

I've been working on setting an existing Ionic 2 project on a Apple Mac machine.

I've duplicated my project as it is described [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2361#issuecomment-58474409).

After solving some Xcode issues, finally the app opens on an iPhone iOS physical device but shows a blank screen after the splash screen.

I found how to get some log displayed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571650/catching-all-javascript-unhandled-exceptions/16185951#16185951). The log input lead me to that [SO thread: "cannot find module ionic-native"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43583032/cannot-find-module-ionic-native).

I concluded that I had to update my project code to match the [new settings  to handle ionic-native plugins](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/).

For each plugin I applied the following process: `ionic plugin rm [plugin name]`, `ionic plugin add [plugin name]`, `npm install --save @ionic-native/[plugin name]`.

I reviewed my code to change where needed, in some `components` and `providers` from:
`{ NativePlugin1, NativePlugin2 } from 'ionic-native';`
To:
`{ NativePlugin1 } from '@ionic-native/native-plugin-1';`
`{ NativePlugin2 } from '@ionic-native/native-plugin-2';`

I modified my [ionic project folder]/src/app/app.module.ts and added:

```
// all declaration as it was like "import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';"
//plus declarations added to match new rules and add plugin in providers section
{ NativePlugin1 } from '@ionic-native/native-plugin-1';
{ NativePlugin2 } from '@ionic-native/native-plugin-2';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [...
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [...
  ],
  providers: [
    NativePlugin1,
    NativePlugin2,
    ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I deleted from my package.json the line `"ionic-native": "^2.7.0",` as it is suggested in the [solution of the SO thread I am referencing to](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/):

> You need to remove  "ionic-native": "^3.5.0" from your package.json and after that run npm i.

Then I launched in that order: `sudo npm cache clear`, `sudo npm install`, and finally `ionic build ios`, for which I get:

> "Error: Failed to transpile program"

And above this error I see plenty of errors related to the `ionic-native` like this one:

> [14:22:15]  typescript: src/services/custom-http/custom-http.ts, line:XX
>
> ```
>        Property 'type' does not exist on type 'typeof Network'.
>
>  LXX:     return Network.type;
> ```

**I feel stuck now so if anyone has a hint it  would be welcome.**

**To complete here are some additional info:**
`ionic info` gives:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.4
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.1
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014
```

And my `package.json` is like this:

```
{
  "name": "my project",
  "author": "my name",
  "homepage": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch",
    "serve:before": "watch",
    "emulate:before": "build",
    "deploy:before": "build",
    "build:before": "build",
    "run:before": "build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.2",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/insomnia": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/vibration": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.0.3",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ng2-translate": "^3.2.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "latest",
    "typescript": "2.0.3"
  },
  "description": "MyProject: An Ionic project",
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": []
}
```

**Some update after @suraj input:**
I ve updated my package.json such as:

```
{
  "name": "MyIonicProject",
  "author": "author name",
  "homepage": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch",
    "serve:before": "watch",
    "emulate:before": "build",
    "deploy:before": "build",
    "build:before": "build",
    "run:before": "build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/insomnia": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/vibration": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.0.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4",
    "ng2-translate": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "latest",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  },
  "description": "LpjcaIonic: An Ionic project",
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": []
}
```

I followed the [change log update for ionic 3](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300-2017-04-05).

I deleted the `node_modules` directory of my project launching:`sudo rm -rf node_modules/` then did an `nom install` , `ionic platform rm ios`,`ionic platform add ios`, and finally  `ionic build ios`.

I looked in the log, here is their content:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@4.5.0
3 info using node@v6.9.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle [MyIonicProject]@~prebuild: [MyIonicProject]@
6 silly lifecycle [MyIonicProject]@~prebuild: no script for prebuild, continuing
7 info lifecycle [MyIonicProject]@~build: [MyIonicProject]@
8 verbose lifecycle [MyIonicProject]@~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle [MyIonicProject]@~build: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Users/my_mac/Documents/[MyIonicProject]/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/my_mac/Library/Android/sdk:/Users/my_mac/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/my_mac/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
10 verbose lifecycle [MyIonicProject]@~build: CWD: /Users/my_mac/Documents/[MyIonicProject]
11 silly lifecycle [MyIonicProject]@~build: Args: [ '-c', 'ionic-app-scripts build' ]
12 silly lifecycle [MyIonicProject]@~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle [MyIonicProject]@~build: Failed to exec build script
14 verbose stack Error: [MyIonicProject]@ build: `ionic-app-scripts build`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:279:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid LpjcaIonic@
16 verbose cwd /Users/my_mac/Documents/[MyIonicProject]
17 verbose Darwin 16.5.0
18 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
19 verbose node v6.9.1
20 verbose npm  v4.5.0
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno 1
23 error LpjcaIonic@ build: `ionic-app-scripts build`
23 error Exit status 1
24 error Failed at the [MyIonicProject]@ build script 'ionic-app-scripts build'.
24 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
24 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the [MyIonicProject] package,
24 error not with npm itself.
24 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
24 error     ionic-app-scripts build
24 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
24 error     npm bugs [MyIonicProject]
24 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
24 error     npm owner ls [MyIonicProject]
24 error There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Additional input to @suraj, the class `CustomHttpService`, it is a service located in `[project]/services/custom-http/custom-http.ts` and injected in the `Providers` section of `app.module.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions, RequestMethod, Request } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
// import { Network } from 'ionic-native';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';


@Injectable()
export class CustomHttpService {
    //other code    

    public connection = () => {
        return Network.type;
    }


    public onDisconnect = ():Observable<any> => {
        return Network.onDisconnect();
    }

    public onConnect = ():Observable<any> => {
        return Network.onConnect();
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have updated ionic-native to 3.x.. however your core `ionic-angular` is still in `2.0.0-rc0` and also all other dependencies are older.
Typescript used currently is changed to 2.2.
You will need to update your package.json to the current [starter app version](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/package.json) if you plan to move to ionic native 3.

Also check the [changelog](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for any breaking changes in ionic for your code.

Also you need set each of the ionic native plugins as providers and inject in your constructor and use. 
Check [the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network).
In your app.module.ts,

```
    @NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    Network 
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In your custom.http.ts

```
constructor(public http:Http,public network:Network
        ){
        console.log("CustomHttpService() starts");
    }
//..other code 


public connection = () => {
        return this.network.type;
    }
```

Comment: I did what you suggested but the same error is still thrown. I detailed my question with those new actions I did.

Comment: Change your build and serve commands in script block to the referred package.json..if that doesn't work try updating your ionic cli

Comment: do you have an example of what you mean by: "Change your build and serve commands in script block to the referred package.json" ?

Comment: `scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },`

Comment: The errors are from running the script in package.json. This is run when you do ionic serve

Comment: thanks for your help @suraj, I am just going nuts with this now (it adds up on top of some Mac settings stuff to be able to use a iOS 9.3 device), I haven t started to work on what I really want to work on.

Comment: I ve changed the script part with of package.json: `  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch",
    "serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "serve:before": "watch",
    "emulate:before": "build",
    "deploy:before": "build",
    "build:before": "build",
    "run:before": "build"
  },`

Comment: still get the same error, I ve tried a `ionic serve`, it shows the same error when compiling: [14:22:15] typescript: src/services/custom-http/custom-http.ts, line:XX

       Property 'type' does not exist on type 'typeof Network'.

 LXX:     return Network.type;

Comment: something weird: in the [official doc][1], it says: ` The CLI requires Node 4.X (Node 5.X has been known to cause a number of issues).` \n\r Whereas when I launch `ionic build ios` it says: `Failed at the MyIonicProject@ build script 'ionic-app-scripts build'.
npm ERR! **Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.**
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the LpjcaIonic package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.`  [1]:http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/

Comment: I wonder if I miss something with Typescript, because all the error like `Network type` are the import changed from 'ionic-native' to @ionic-native' and I don't see the update on the *.ts files reflected on the *.js files.

Comment: you need set each of the ionic native plugins as providers and inject in your constructor and use

Comment: That's the major change from ionic native 2 to 3

Comment: I ve added the custom-http-service at the bottom of the question

Comment: I already did the updates in ngModule (i ve described it a the beginning of my question). Regarding the injection of a `ionic-native` like `Network` inside a `custom service`: it did not work in the past. Checkout the answer I received on that question that was precisely on that topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40314851/ionic2-cordova-sqlite-storage-how-to-use-sqlite-as-a-service

Comment: in ionic native 3.x..it is a provider.. And you are not setting a new object to a plugin. That answer is about a db.as mentioned in the answer.. Go through the docs

Comment: You were right @suraj: It worked out to inject a provider inside another provider. Now I have other problems but at least it compiles, I can start it on the device, and get a blank screen probably because of some corrupt JS (to be continued). Thanks for your time and your effort to provide me some relevant guidances.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same error and after filtering through the code there was a syntax error with a missing comma. Try looking in your app.module.ts file. Hope it helps.